# Case insensitive user input

Tags: python

```py
pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while pizza != "S/M/L/XL":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = "S/M/L/XL"
    pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
```

This is what I have buts its dosent work

Comment: if someone types `S`, would you expect `"S" != "S/M/L/XL"` to evaluate to True or to False?

Comment: I suspect that this is an exercise about logical connectives (`and`, `or`,...) and possibly the `upper` and `lower` methods of strings.

Comment: When someone types S,M,L,or XL the line should then finish

Comment: But do you think that `"S" == "S/M/L/XL"` is True? have you tried evaluating that in an interactive python intepreter?

Answer (score 1):

Make the list of allowable characters a set, and check if the input is in that set. Also, force the input to an uppercase character, so the user does not have to worry about it.

Also, having `str` on your input is redundant, `input` returns a string by default.

```
pizza = input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?').upper()

while pizza not in ('S','M','L','XL'):
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?").upper()
```

Comment: we don't, that was a line I forgot to remove

Answer (score 1):

```
pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while pizza != "S" and pizza != "M" and pizza!="L" and pizza!="XL"and pizza!="s"and pizza!="m"and pizza!="l"and pizza!="xl":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
print(pizza.upper())
```

is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I wrote the code to a function.

```
def asking():
    pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL? ')).upper()
    if pizza != 'S' and pizza != 'M' and pizza != 'L' and pizza != 'XL':
        print('That is not a valid answer!')
        asking()
    else:
        print('Okay, your pizza\'s size will be: {}'.format(pizza))

asking()
```

Comment: You can use `if pizza not in ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']:` in line 3.

Comment: Yeah that's true.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to not reuse variable names. It'll help you truly 'name' things. Is 'pizza' the best name for the variable? How about 'size' or 'order'? This will help you spot bugs more easily. Let's rename the variables.

```
size_of_pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while size_of_pizza != "S/M/L/XL":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    pizza = "S/M/L/XL"  # See? Here you're manipulating the value of 'pizza' inside a 'while' loop. That's not advised, you can remove this line
    size_of_pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
```

Let's remove that line. We end up with:

```
size_of_pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while size_of_pizza != "S/M/L/XL":
    print(" That is not a valid answer")
    size_of_pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
```

Oh, but note that you're asking if size_of_pizza != "S/M/L/XL". That's not right! You have several correct answers, so you either need several 'if' clauses or some type of list or iterator. How about this...

```
size_of_pizza = str(input('Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?'))

while size_of_pizza not in ["S","M","L","XL"]:
    print("That is not a valid answer")
    size_of_pizza = str(input("Which size pizza do you want: S/M/L/XL?"))
```

Much better!
But you still have work to do! Let me ask you:

- What happens if the user inputs a number (You may have already thought of this but you should be aware of this decision!)
- Should size_of_pizza always be forced to become a string?

Good luck!

Comment: Note: `input()` always returns a string